# Tomcat - 404 page not found issue

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat9

When I start tomcat 9 using eclipse, and then navigate to http://localhost:8080, it gives 404 - page not found and throws error: "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists". However when I goto tomcat directory and start the process using tomcat9w.exe and then execute http://localhost:8080, page displays perfectly. What might be wrong?

```
Elipse tomcat startup logs:

Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.16
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 4 2019 16:30:29 UTC
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.16.0
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_201-b09
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\vijay\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\vijay\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\vijay\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.21] using APR version [1.6.5].
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018]
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [697] milliseconds
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:15 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 26, 2019 7:24:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [388] milliseconds

I see the tomcat server in eclipse is started without any problem but can not reach to default website..

THanks
```

Comment: Maybe it's listening on another port? Is the tomcat on your eclipse the same installation as the one you ran manually?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your "HTTP 404: File not found" probably means you're missing an "index.jsp" in your Eclipse project.
2. Running Tomcat from Eclipse is *NOT* the same as running tomcat from a command prompt (or, equivalently, as a Windows service).

   Even if you point to the *SAME* Tomcat installation (Eclipse > Services > Add), Eclipse will execute from a *different* subfolder that "tomcat9w.exe".

   You can see this in the log you posted: `C:\Users\vijay\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core`.  Try starting both ways, and compare "CATALINA_BASE".

---

Thank you for the additional info.  Specifically:

1. Q: This is from *successfully* starting Tomcat, correct?  Presumably from running tomcat9w.exe, correct?

   ```
   [26/Feb/2019:17:27:56 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11488 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - 
   [26/Feb/2019:17:27:56 -0600] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103 Eclipse Catina Logs for tomcat: 127.0.0.1 - - 

   [26/Feb/2019:19:13:38 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1074 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - 
   [26/Feb/2019:19:13:43 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1074 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - 
   [26/Feb/2019:19:13:57 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1074 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - -
   ```
2. Q: These are a completely different set of log messages, from running Tomcat from Eclipse, correct?
3. you would *NOT* get HTTP 404 unless Tomcat "couldn't find" the requested resource.  Here, that resource is "/".  Which means it expects to find an "index file", such as "index.html", "index.jsp" or equivalent.
4. For an Eclipse project, that means an "index.jsp" in the root of your "webapp" folder.
5. QUESTIONS:

   Q: Are statements 1) and 2) above correct?

   Q: Does your tomcat9w.exe" startup print CATALINA_BASE and port#?  If so, please copy/paste them to your original post.

   Q: Does your Eclipse log print any error messages?  If so, please copy/paste them into your original post.

   Q: Do you have an "index.jsp"?  Where is it located in your Eclipse project?  Directly under "webapp"?  Do you also see it anywhere under "C:\Users\vijay\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core"?  Go into Windows Explorer and look.

Please post back what you find.

Comment: I do have index.jsp file in my eclipse as startup for the web project. Where I am hitting roadblock is, when i just want to start the startup site of tomcat.. Just to understand you clearly, if I start project from eclipse, i can not reach to default tomcat site? Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: This is what I have in modules.xml <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<modules>

<module serverId="Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost" moduleId="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebApp-01"/>

<module serverId="Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost" moduleId="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:webapp-01"/>

<module serverId="Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost" moduleId="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloWorld"/>

</modules>

Comment: I compared both catina base logs and see this: I am not able to understand what is causing 404 still.          Tomcat 9 catina base:

0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [26/Feb/2019:17:27:56 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11488
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [26/Feb/2019:17:27:56 -0600] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103
Eclipse Catina Logs for tomcat:

127.0.0.1 - - [26/Feb/2019:19:13:38 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1074
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [26/Feb/2019:19:13:43 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1074
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [26/Feb/2019:19:13:57 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 1074
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [26/Feb/2019:19:14:07 -

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to test a project to startup in eclipse is by right clicking the project and click
Run As > Run on Server

If this work, then your tomcat initially wasn't pointing to the project. Thus unable to locate a index.jsp/html.

If you do not have a project and wanted to start tomcat from eclipse and shows the default tomcat homepage, you can do this.

Double click the Tomcat Server under Servers and from that option select this.
[image: Use Tomcat Installation]

It should now work.

Comment: I think this is all disabled in my eclipse.. however I made it work by recompiling my projects in eclipse.. When I directly invoke the url-mapping url, it works and displays the page however now, when I am using post method to invoke servlet, it is throwing  error above.. Once again thanks both Paul and Daniel for taking time out to review and reply on this post.